# xcode triggers same breakpoint repeatedly only when stepping through

Tags: ios, xcode, breakpoints

I'm on Xcode 4.5 (although this has happened with previous version) and I find that when I set breakpoints, sometimes they hit repeatedly whereas NSLogging my logic is only traversed once. I've ruled out the usual suspects such as some basic problem in my logic that is inadvertently calling into the breakpoint when the program stops at one.  My conclusion is that there is a bug with the debugger that makes the breakpoint hit repeatedly, but this seems to happen even when I step through a few lines of code then continue to run.

Has anyone seen this occur before or even better know a way to alleviate this issue?